# react router how can I render only the component in his route whiout the others?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

How can I show only `Modificar` component in `/Modificar` and the both `BasicTable` and `FormTareas` in

```
<BrowserRouter>
    {
        <Switch>
            <Route
                exact
                path="/Modificar"
                component={() => (
                    <Modificar
                        tareaACambiar={tareaACambiar}
                        actualizar={actualizar}
                    />
                )}
             />
        </Switch>
    }

    <FormTareas
        handleChange={handleChange}
        handleSubmit={handleSubmit}
        validateForm={validateForm}
    ></FormTareas>
    <BasicTable
        tareas={tareas}
        eliminarTarea={eliminarTarea}
        modificarTarea={modificarTarea}
        ></BasicTable>
</BrowserRouter>
```

Is working but when I scroll in `/Modificar` the other two components too render. I try put the other in a switch and a route but then the function that I pass doesn't work :(
The code is here https://github.com/JavierLoera/Lista-Tareas.
and the preview is here https://lista-tareas-gilt.vercel.app/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

because they are added after your routing logic, to avoid that u need to add them in another route

Comment: i try that but the function that i pass as props doesnt work :( anyways i will try whit the answer codeinaire
 because i was putting one route for each component instead of one thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like this:

```
 <BrowserRouter>
                {
                  <Switch>
                    <Route exact path="/">
                      <FormTareas
                        handleChange={handleChange}
                        handleSubmit={handleSubmit}
                        validateForm={validateForm}
                      ></FormTareas>
                      <BasicTable
                        tareas={tareas}
                        eliminarTarea={eliminarTarea}
                        modificarTarea={modificarTarea}
                      ></BasicTable>
                    </Route>
                    <Route
                      exact
                      path="/Modificar"
                      component={() => (
                        <Modificar
                          tareaACambiar={tareaACambiar}
                          actualizar={actualizar}
                        />
                      )}
                    />
                  </Switch>
                }
              </BrowserRouter>
```

When you go to either "/" or "/Modificar" it'll display only those components that are within the Route component.